# how can I compare HashMaps with different keys?

Tags: java

I have a clustering algorithm storing the clusters in `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

I need to compare it with the ground truth which is stored in another `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

The keys are not the same, because the array is created by incremental clustering, so I was wondering how can I compare the original clusters with the generated ones.

I'm using NMI and BCUBED as clustering evaluation measures, but my problem is how to refer to the same cluster (ArrayList) if they have different keys..

Any ideas?

Comment: so are you saying tha 'ground truth' hash map is generally a proper superset of the maps from incremental clustering?

Comment: What do you mean by the keys are not the same? They are not of the same type.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy As result the clustering algorithm should give exactly the original HashMap, but the results are never perfect, so I should measure how far the clusters are from the original ones. All the documents ( ArrayList<String> objects ) are there but they might be in different clusters or there might be more or less clusters (more or less HashMap items).

Comment: @doc_180 I mean that since I'm creating the clusters from raw data, I'm assigning new keys (0, 1, 2.. ) as I create new clusters. The same cluster in the original and generated data do not necessarily have the same key. Also it might have too many or too little docs.

Comment: This is really unfortunate, as the very purpose of a key is to be able to find and identify the data .....

Comment: @Ingo yeah I see. What do you suggest me to do ? I actually need to compare the results with the expected results, and I need some data structure to store the clusters. I can compare the doc IDs, but I cannot refer to the clusters IDs because the latter are generated in different order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on how your class is set up and how the `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` is really meant to work, but my inclination is that you should have a Hash of your keys.  So as you're assigning clusters you could do something like this.

Original Data:

```
Hashmap<String, ArrayList<String>> = key: Array Of Original Data
```

You would store what is in each cluster as a function of:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> = Cluster Key: Array of Original Data Keys
```

That would give you a mechanism to cycle through the objects that are in each cluster and still maintain the state of the original object, does that make sense?  You'd ultimately then be able to write something akin to:

```
for(String clusterKey : clusterMap.keySet()){
    for(String itemKey : clusterMap.get(clusterKey)){
       calculateDistance(centroid, originalMap.get(itemKey);
    }
}
```

That is a gross oversimplification, but should get you going in the right direction.

**edit**
I also assumer there is a HashMap of the centroids to the clusters themselves.  So it the `calculateDistance()` method could be rewritted as `calculateDistance(centroidMap.get(clusterKey), originalMap.get(itemKey));`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create a reverse HashMap in which the KeyObj is a new object with an ArrayList and a counter.

In the reverse HashMap, the counter of the key will be the number of equal ArrayLists.

Now the comparing algorithm is easy:
Iterate through the values of the first HashMap and search for the value as a key of the new HashMap. If the key was found and the counter is 0, or the key was not found, return false. Else, do count-- and continue to the next iteration. 
At the end, return true.

Comment: hi, does this work only if the keyObj is exactly the same? I mean, the same reference ? Or also equal objects but stored in 2 differently spots in memory are ok ?

Comment: I actually don't see how this might work, because each KeyObj which is the arraylist with all document ids, might be different from the original. I mean, this is actually the error I want to measure. How can I use it as key if it is not the same ?

Comment: Also, I don't know which value to assign to the counter, because I can only check how many docs in common each cluster has while iterating, but not in advance.

Comment: @user680406 You could make a hash of the (content) KeyObj (and don't forget about the String Constant Pool)

Comment: @Marco Sorry, what do you exactly mean ? Not sure I got it. Do you mean to store the Value of the original HashMap as key in the new generated HashMap ?